# What is the point of an AWS session token if you still have to use the access key and secret key along with it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, session, oauth, bearer-token

I'm trying to develop an OAuth solution for an AWS API using C# lambda functions.

I'm able to get a session token using the access key and secret key of a user I set up with invoke permissions for the API Gateway and functions thereon.  I even have an endpoint that takes the client_id and client_secret and grant_type (client_credentials) as is standard for OAuth2.

I was then going to use the session token ONLY, which expires, to access the API endpoints.

However, when I try to find a way to validate the session token, all I can seem to find are solutions that use the access key, the secret key AND the temporary session token.  I just want to use the temporary session token as a bearer token in the header under Authorization, as is standard for OAuth2.

Authorization: Bearer <session_token>

Is there any way to accomplish this or have I gone so far down a rabbit hole that there's nothing left to do but start over???

Comment: This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-aws-lambda-authorizers-with-a-third-party-identity-provider-to-secure-amazon-api-gateway-rest-apis/) might provide some help. Also, when you are talking about "access key, secret key and temporary session token", you may be referring to STS credentials, for example the credentials that a Lambda function has by virtue of it being configured to launch with a specific IAM Role that gives the Lambda function temporary credentials to access the AWS resources it needs, such as S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables etc.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the session token is only good for accessing other AWS services and that the only way to use it is with the aws_access_key_id and the aws_secret_key_id and there is no way to get any useful information, if only if the session token has expired, except by also using the session_token along with the credentials that were used to get the session_token in the first place?

Comment: Ignoring bearer tokens, JWTS etc. for a moment, a client that wants to make an API request to an AWS service has to supply either a pair (access key and secret key, which are long-term credentials associated with an IAM user) or a triple (access key, secret key, and session token, which are short-term credentials associated with an IAM role). OK, back to API Gateway authorization - APIG supports multiple authorization mechanisms, including [Lambda authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) which support bearer token.

Comment: This OAuth2 [example](https://github.com/aws-samples/openbanking-brazilian-auth-samples) might also help with the bigger picture.

Comment: Also highly recommend Alex DeBrie's articles on API Gateway auth [here](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/lambda-custom-authorizers/) and [here](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/api-gateway-elements/). Apologies for sending you so much reading material!